# Trying to put random strings into a file

Tags: string, file, random, repeat

I am trying to insert random strings into a .txt file. My code is as follows:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class fileProcessing{
   public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception{
      letter();
   }

   public static void letter() throws Exception{
      int count = 0;
         PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new File("nums.txt"));
            while (count < 7 ){
              Random rand = new Random();
                  int randomNum = 97 + rand.nextInt((122 - 97) + 1);
                     char a = (char)randomNum;
                        out.print(a);
                        count++;
      }
   }
}
```

I'm trying to put a row of 7 random letters in a .txt file about 400 or so times. My code allows me to put in only a row of 7 letters. I'm not sure how to get the other 399 lines in. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Use a nested loop

Comment: Have you tried another loop of 400 encompassing while loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `nested loop` that contains the loop you have already written. What this does is, after you generate one word, do a new iteration, writing another word in your file.

```
import java.util.*
import java.io.*;

class FileProcessing
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        letters();
    }

    public static void letters() throws IOException
    {
        int count;
        PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new File("nums.txt"));

        /*Outer loop. When the loop on the inside finishes generating 
         *a word, this loop will iterate again.
         */
        for(int i=0; i<400; ++i)
        {
             count=0;
             /*your current while loop*/
             while (count < 7)
             {
                 Random rand = new Random();
                 int randomNum = 97 + rand.nextInt((122-97)+1);
                 char a = (char) randomNum;
                 out.print(a);
                 count++;
             }
             //print new line so all words are in a separate line
             out.println();
        }
        //close PrintStream
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Learn more on nested loops here: http://www.javawithus.com/tutorial/nested-loops

Comment: This works except for the out.print("\n"). It needs to be a println. Thank you for the answer though.